# Finding general solution to the following DE: $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2 + 2y + x + xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I found this question in my workbook, and in the question it gives me a hint that this equation is first-order separable. So I have been trying to separate y and x but I cannot seem to do it. I might just be stupid and can't figure it out, if anyone could show me how or maybe suggest another solution that would be great, Thanks.

Eqn: $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2 + 2y + x + xy$

Comment: Linear DE, of the form $y'(x)-a(x)y(x)=b(x)$, the standard case, what is stopping you?

Comment: @Jai: **Hint:** can you factor the RHS into something helpful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factoring the $y$ we get:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=2+x+y(2+x)$. Now again factoring out the $2+x$ we get:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(2+x)(1+y)$. We divide both sides by $(1+y)$ to obtain:

$\frac{1}{1+y}dy=(2+x)dx$. Integrating we obtain

$\int \frac{1}{1+y}dy= \int (2+x)dx$ which gives us:

$\ln(y+1)=2x+\frac{x^2}{2}+C$. Applying $e$ to both sides of the equation we get:

$y+1=e^{2x+\frac{x^2}{2}+C}$ and so $y=e^{2x+\frac{x^2}{2}+C}-1$.

Comment: (+1) I was writing up an answer that was essentially the same.

Comment: They let you post from prison?

Comment: My influence gets me computer privileges.

Comment: Maybe had you spent more time hiding and less time posting on SE you'd be free. :) Okay I'll stop.